# Visual Studio Code lensing for Javascript/ AJAX

Tags: visual-studio

I am using Visual Studio 2019 Professional and have code lensing enabled. Therefore, I get an indication when the function/ method is called from another .NET/ C# class in my project.

Now, I have some JavaScript file in which there are AJAX calls which call REST API endpoints. My question is that is there any way or is there a VS plugin that allows for code lensing on AJAX calls? In other words I would like to know which methods/ functions are being called from AJAX or client-side?

Thanks for your help.